# Where does Spyder 3 (for Linux) keep track of open tabs and recently opened files?

Tags: python, spyder

I upgraded to a new Linux Mint machine and I want to keep the settings of my fav editor (Spyder 3.3.6, Mint 19, Ubuntu bionic).

Specifically, at Spyder's startup I want to open the same files that it opened on the old machine.

When Spyder starts on the old machine, it opens about 30 python files. These files are all stored in different folders. I use the files to refer to existing code, so it is great to have them always open.

The folders with *.py files are all present on the new machine on the same locations (/home/myusername/... etc).

It would be great if Spyder on my new machine opens the same files at startup. Can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Our configuration files are saved in

```
~/.config/spyder-py3
```

if your Linux distro follows the XDG standard, or simply in

```
~/.spyder-py3
```

if it doesn't, or if you're on Windows or macOS.

Comment: Yes! It's there in spyder.ini: recent_files =